# How to make a confusion matrix based on values from all the pairs of columns of a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, confusion-matrix

I have a PySpark dataframe

```
simpleData = [("person0",1, 1, 0), \
    ("person1",1, 1, 1), \
    ("person2",1, 0, 0), \
    ("person3",0 ,0, 0 ), \
  ]
columns= ['persons_name','A', 'B', 'C']
exp = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)

exp.show()
```

It contains only binary values (0 and 1)
This looks like-

```
+------------+---+---+---+
|persons_name|  A|  B|  C|
+------------+---+---+---+
|     person0|  1|  1|  0|
|     person1|  1|  1|  1|
|     person2|  1|  0|  0|
|     person3|  0|  0|  0|
+------------+---+---+---+
```

We need to initialize the confusion matrix with zeros like,

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  0|  0|  0|
|  B|  0|  0|  0|
|  C|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Now I want to populate the confusion matrix in the following way-
For every row in our dataframe **exp**, I want to increase the counter of the confusion matrix for all the pairs of columns having values = 1 in dataframe.

For example, for **person0**, there is only 1 pair of columns, A and B, which have value = 1. So we increase the value of the confusion matrix at (A, B) and (B, A).
This would look like-

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  0|  1|  0|
|  B|  1|  0|  0|
|  C|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

For **person1**, there are 3 pairs of columns, (A, B), (A, C) and (B, C), which have value = 1. So we increase the value of the confusion matrix at (A, B), (B, A), (A, C), (C, A), (B, C), and (C, B).

Now the updated confusion matrix would look like-

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  0|  2|  1|
|  B|  2|  0|  1|
|  C|  1|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

There are no such pairs for **person2** and **person3**. So we don't update the confusion matrix.
The final confusion matrix would look like-

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  0|  2|  1|
|  B|  2|  0|  1|
|  C|  1|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

How can I achieve this is PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine your original data frame is a matrix with columns `A, B, C`, the confusion matrix can be calculated by multiplying the original matrix with its own transpose. In other words, **the entry for row `A` column `B` is simply the dot product of column `A` and `B` except the diagonal**, so you can basically have a nested loop over the columns, calculate the dot product for every pair of columns.

*Also In general, the number of columns should be small enough to be manageable on local host, you can collect the result into a 2D list or numpy array:*

```
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
res = np.array([
  [exp.agg(f.sum(f.col(x) * f.col(y))).first()[0] if x != y else 0 for y in cols] 
  for x in cols
])

res
#[[0 2 1]
# [2 0 1]
# [1 1 0]]
```